# How to change Vob owner and vob group?

Tags: clearcase

I tried to change vob owner and vob group.
It throws an error like:

```
Error:No "ClearCase" group found
Error:unknown protection styles
```

Comment: What command did you run?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the technote "[About changing the ownership of a VOB and its objects on Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146535)"

> - Run the `fix_prot` utility as follows:

```
    fix_prot -r -root -chown <new_owner> -chgrp <new_primary_group> <path to VOB storage directory>
```

> `fix_prot` will remove all additional groups from the VOBs group list.
>   If there were additional groups in the VOBs group list, add those groups back by running `protectvob`.
>
> - Restart the ClearCase services from the ClearCase applet in the control panel.
> - Add the additional groups back to the VOBs group list by running protectvob:

```
    cleartool protectvob -add_group <groupname, groupname2, ...> <vob-storage-pname>
```

You have other tools to manage the vob, listed in "[Summary of protection commands and utilities used with ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21211784)", like [`project_vob`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protectvob.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-2-1-23-4) (used above).